# Как убрать лишний перенос строк, при вставке своего сокращения(snippet'a)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, сниппет

Как убрать лишний перенос строк, при вставке своего сокращения (snippet'a)?
смысл в том, что после вставки (сокращение+tab+tab) оно переносится на следущую строчку, что не желательно. Как это избежать ?

Да любой код.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>main</Title>
      <Shortcut>ma</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <References />
      <Imports />
      <Declarations />
      <Code Language="csharp" Kind="" Delimiter="$"><![CDATA[static void Main(string[] args){

}]]></Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

к примеру такой. Оставляет пустую строку и создаёт на следующей

Comment: Нет такой проблемы, если сниппет описан правильно. Приведите его код.

Comment: вот пример, который не оставляет пустой строки и не делает перевода строк: http://pastebin.com/fbyhS3dA  Ваш сниппет, кстати, тоже не переносит на следующую строку на дефолтных настройках Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Проблема не решена.

Comment: @DenisJNewb Приведите пример ваших настроек Visual Studio.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky каких-то конкретно настроек или всех ? Если всех, то как я могу это сделать?

Comment: Настроек, которые могут влиять на проблему. Как выше пишет @Zufir, возможно все дело именно в том, как вы настроили редактор.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Я не знаю какие настройки могли бы на это повлиять, иначе не было бы проблем самому с ними разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

Правила для переносов строк для C# в Visual Studio можно изменить в главном меню:
`Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Formatting -> New Lines`

А в сниппете попробуйте заменить тег на следующий:

```
<Code Language="csharp" Kind="" Delimiter="$">
  <![CDATA[static void Main(string[] args){ }]]></Code>
```

Comment: 1. Стоят последние 3 галки там. Но для теста убирал - не помогает.

2. Этот код идентичен моему, за исключением отсутствия переноса строки после символа "{"

Answer (score 1):

Вот что нужно сделать и все будет работать:

```
<Code Language="csharp" Kind="" Delimiter="$"><![CDATA[static void Main(string[] args){$end$

}]]></Code>
```

Если коротко, то просто надо поставить `$end$` туда, где надо чтобы заканчивалась строка.

Пример для `Console.ReadLine` сниппета:

```
...
<![CDATA[Console.ReadLine($end$);]]>
...
```

Comment: В следующий раз, не стоит удалять сообщение, чтобы его улучшить. Его можно [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1324919/edit).